# Can not access destructor from python C++ wrapper

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I'm trying to wrap some existing C++ functions to python. I simplified my problem to the code listed below:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class A { ~A( ); };
void func( const A& );

int main( int argc, char** argv ){
    boost::python::def( "func", func );
}
```

I get error about accessing private destructor A::~A. Note, A::~A must be inaccessible in my case and I can not modify existing C++ code. Note2, sample above will compile if func get pointer instead of reference.

```
void func( const A* );
```

I would like to explain boost::python that it must not delete object A in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use an auxiliary function that accepts a `A*`, and delegates to `func(const A&)`.

```cpp
boost::python::def("func", +[](A* a) { return func(*a); });
```

When a function is exposed directly through [`boost::python::def()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/def.html#def-spec), Boost.Python will attempt to register converters for arguments that pass between the language barrier.  To mitigate the chance of dangling references, Python will do a by-value conversion for any non-pointer arguments.  By using the auxiliary, a from-Python converter by pointer will be used during function dispatch.

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f58a6b420088777b) using an auxiliary function to avoid a by-value conversion.  It also shows how to use `boost::shared_ptr` to  explicitly customize the destruction of a class exposed through Boost.Python:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

namespace {
int func_count = 0;
} // namespace

// Legacy model.
class spam
{
private:
  ~spam() {};
};

// Legacy API.
void func(const spam&)
{
  ++func_count;
};

/// @brief Factory function to create Spam instances with
///        a custom deleter.
boost::shared_ptr<spam> make_spam()
{
  // Create a new spam instance with a no-op deleter.
  auto no_op = +[](void*) {};
  return boost::shared_ptr<spam>(new spam(), no_op);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  // Expose class A with a custom deleter.
  python::class_<spam, boost::shared_ptr<spam>,
      boost::noncopyable>("Spam", python::no_init)
    .def("__init__", python::make_constructor(&make_spam))
    ;

  // Use an auxiliary function to avoid by-value conversion 
  // at the language boundary.  This prevents Boost.Python 
  // from creating instance holders that would hold the value
  // as an rvalue.
  python::def("func", +[](spam* spam){ return func(*spam); });

  python::def("get_count", +[]() { return func_count; });
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> spam = example.Spam()
>>> assert(0 == example.get_count())
>>> example.func(spam)
>>> assert(1 == example.get_count())
>>> try:
...     example.func(1)
...     assert(False)
... except TypeError:
...     pass
... 
>>> assert(1 == example.get_count())
```

Note that in the above example, the `spam` instances are managed by a `boost::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter that does not delete the instance.  This hook enables custom strategies to invoke when an object is no longer referenced by Python or C++.

Comment: I have a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013723/unary-in-front-of-lambda) about your answer. Maybe you can take a look at it?